# In Google Cloud's "built-in image object detection algorithm" documentation, what is config.yaml?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

In the [official GCP documentation for the built-in image object detection classifier](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/object-detection-start), Step 2 under "Submit a training job" says:

> Submit the job:
>
> cloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_ID \
>
> --region=$REGION \
>
> --config=config.yaml \
>   ...

This is the first reference to "config.yaml" on this page.

Has anyone been able to implement this example?

Here is the code from the above documentation page in full, including a correction on line 2 (the original had a JOB_DIR starting with gs://gs://, which threw an error):

```
PROJECT_ID="myapp"
# Original:
#BUCKET_NAME="gs://mybucket/"
# Correction:
BUCKET_NAME="mybucket"
REGION="us-central1"

gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
gcloud config set compute/region $REGION

# Set paths to the training and validation data.
TRAINING_DATA_PATH="gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/built-in/image/coco/train*"
VALIDATION_DATA_PATH="gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/built-in/image/coco/val*"

# Specify the Docker container for your built-in algorithm selection.
IMAGE_URI="gcr.io/cloud-ml-algos/image_object_detection:latest"

DATASET_NAME="coco"
ALGORITHM="object_detection"
MODEL_NAME="${DATASET_NAME}_${ALGORITHM}_model"

# Give a unique name to your training job.
DATE="$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')"
JOB_ID="${MODEL_NAME}_${DATE}"

# Make sure you have access to this Cloud Storage bucket.
JOB_DIR="gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/algorithms_training/${MODEL_NAME}/${DATE}"

gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_ID \
--region=$REGION \
--config=config.yaml \
--job-dir=$JOB_DIR \
-- \
--training_data_path=$TRAINING_DATA_PATH \
--validation_data_path=$VALIDATION_DATA_PATH \
--train_batch_size=64 \
--num_eval_images=500 \
--train_steps_per_eval=2000 \
--max_steps=15000 \
--num_classes=90 \
--warmup_steps=500 \
--initial_learning_rate=0.08 \
--fpn_type="nasfpn" \
--aug_scale_min=0.8 \
--aug_scale_max=1.2

gcloud ai-platform jobs describe $JOB_ID
gcloud ai-platform jobs stream-logs $JOB_ID
```

Running the above results in the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) Failed to load YAML from [config.yaml]: Unable to read file [config.yaml]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'config.yaml'
```

Creating an empty config.yaml produces this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

From the [gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training):

> Path to the job configuration file. This file should be a YAML
>   document (JSON also accepted) containing a Job resource as defined in
>   the API (all fields are optional):
>   https://cloud.google.com/ml/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs

I submitted feedback on this page a couple of weeks ago, but haven't heard back and it is still broken.

What content is required in config.yaml to make this work?

Any and all ideas/suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by replacing this command line argument:

`--config=config.yaml`

With this one:

`--master-image-uri $IMAGE_URI`

Comment: YAML file can have any of the possible (optional or mandatory) arguments stated in the documentation. --master-image-uri is a required field so it should be either specified in the command or in the YAML. In your first error there was no YAML file (but you still where asking it to read it and use it). In the second one it's empty so it gives an error ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'get']. You could have for instance specified the --master-image-uri (and any other job parameters) in the YAML file and wouldn't need to pass them through the command

Comment: Thanks for your solution Richard, I had the same issue. Did you succeed by the way to train with custom code instead of built-in algorithm? I'm having a hard time to do a custom training.